# You have requested a non-existent service "debug.controller_resolver.inner"

Tags: symfony4

I am upgrading a project from symfony 3.4 to symfony 4.4.43.

When I run:

```
console cache:clear --no-debug
```

I get this error:

```
In ContainerBuilder.php line 1030:
You have requested a non-existent service "debug.controller_resolver.inner".
```

If I run the same command without the `--no-debug` option, I get no error.

I do not know where that service is being called.

I ran `composer require symfony/debug-bundle:*` but it says there is nothing to install, update or remove.

Running `./bin/console debug:container | grep inner` shows the service:
`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver  alias for "debug.controller_resolver.inner"`

I have searched around but no luck finding a solution to it and debugging hasn't helped much...

**UPDATE

The error appears because this line was added to services.yml:
`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver: '@debug.controller_resolver.inner'`

and that line was added because a `./bin/console cache:clear --no-debug` (without that line) gives the following error:

```
    In DefinitionErrorExceptionPass.php line 54:

  Cannot autowire service "XXX\MyBundle\EventListener\RunnerListener": argument "$controllerResolver" of method "__construct()" references class "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this class to the existing "controller_resolver" service.
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the dependency injection from the constructor calling the ControllerResolver class and simply instantiating it inside the constructor:

```
$controllerResolver = new ControllerResolver();
```